# Sparkmaker SLA resin not curing

Tags: sla, resin

My model layers are printing much as I expect but the parts when removed from the plate are very soft and flexible and fail to harden any further in sunlight or UV lamplight.  A tall or slender part will bend and distort under its own weight while printing.  I am using LCD-T resin, I have increased time and reduced thicknesses and am now using 0.04 mm layers at 20 s and 255 brightness with no improvement.
Can anyone suggest what I need to change?

Comment: Could it be something wrong with the raw resin? How are you storing it (temperature and lighting conditions)? How old is it?

Comment: can you run a hard-test of the resin by pouring a tiny sample onto a glass surface and leave it out in the sun? Don't tough it though

Comment: This has nothing to do with post-processing.  If the part is sagging in the chamber (or when removed from the plate), then the cure-time per layer (illumination time) is probably set  too short.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the case that the resin separated into layers in the tray. Try mixing the resin well in its container.

I have also heard it can help to filter the resin prior to mixing.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you folks.  The issue was bad/old resin and left in the tank too long.  Replacing all my stocks with fresh and following rigorous stirring and decanting I now have resin curing well during the print.
Sorry to have taken so long to get back to it.